# Feeding answers to frequent posters that show little to no effort in understanding

Tags: discussion

I'm pretty sure you may have noticed that there are users that seem to be using this forum as a got to place for:

- "How To",
- "I have this error, here is my code",
- "Here are my requirements, please help"

kind of Questions.

I usually downvote the question, and/or leave a comment asking for further details on what they have attempted and so on. However, this doesn't stop them from coming back and doing the same thing over and over again.

I know there is a mechanism in place, where if you have x number of highly downvoted questions, you are unable to continue posting (or at least in stackoverflow).

Should we periodically review questions asked by these users (with a high number of posts) and downvote poorly formulated/asked questions? How does the community deal with this kind of behavior?

Or is it fine to have users not really comply with How to Ask and we just ignore their posts?

(This question is concerning more "veteran" users not new members)

Answer (score 6):

I see this quite a bit and it is frustrating, but I don't think it would matter or make a difference if we down vote them into oblivion because they don't care. It's pretty obvious that we are taken advantage of when a user of rep 1 comes on asks a question and never actually accepts the answer or even up vote that it was helpful, which sucks because I've seen a lot of good answers with obvious hard work put in.  I don't know what the answer is but I'm glad you asked it because it's pretty obvious that there are a lot of takers right now..

This community has gotten me to where I am because of sfdcfox, Adrian and Daniel to name a few, and now I feel I need to take the time to pay that back..