# Engaging with users that show little to no effort in learning

Tags: discussion

I had posted [Feeding answers to frequent posters that show little to no effort in understanding](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/feeding-answers-to-frequent-posters-that-show-little-to-no-effort-in-understandi) a while back and unfortuantely it did not get the traction I would have hoped for.

As of lately, there are users who (based on all their post history) seems to strongly depend on this community to get anything done and seems to be a regular habbit of them to post 'How To' questions, or 'Here is my Code, how do I fix it, or what is wrong with it' and failing to demonstrate any sort of effort into resolving by their own (even after 1yr + of participating on the community).

Other than downvoting and leaving a comment and/or voting to close, I understand that not much can be done. However, what are other ppl's thoughts on these types of users?

should we be doing any of the below?

- Provide Generic Answers jsut to give them a hint as to what they
  should be checking and move along?
- Ignore the question, move along.
- Downvote and/or leave a commment and/or Vote to Close?

Stackoverflow seems to take a much harsher approach (which seems to be `Downvote and move along`)
[When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question/252740#252740)

I understand that this is not the same community, however, I imagine we want to avoid having htese users depend on us to get the job done?

Since most of these posts seem to lack any sort of troubleshooting, would it be appropriate to refer them to a post which provides 'How to troubleshoot my code', basically, close as a duplicate of, and refer to a post with troublehsooting steps (Canonical wiki - for code troubleshooting which would be included in -->  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa)?

Comment: +1 I have already adopted the downvote and move along attitude

Comment: I only downvote on spams.For low-quality question  I comment to get more details and as a last resort I vote to close it,

Comment: what about users that have been on the site for some time (1yr+) that dont seem to improve the quality of their posts?  or seem to show little to no effort in researching how to resolve on their own?

Comment: FWIW, when I get a moment, I've got a ton of canonical-qa I plan on posting. Just need to get to writing them.

Comment: @sfdcfox I would be happy to assist you if needed.

Comment: is there a collaborating tool used by moderators, where we can probably help contribute to creating them? idk, google docs or something?

Comment: Pranay and I used a GitHub repo to collaborate on the unit test canonical QAs

Comment: S canonical for debugging/troubleshooting your code, which could reference a couple of existing 'How To's' would be useful?i there a Trello for pending Canonicals (or anything similar to?)

Comment: I could relate this to the instances you too may have experienced and I had the same frustration going through a very *low and poor quality* of posts every time. The overall quality of the post is just poor. There is no formatting, language is not clear, and the issues not clearly highlighted. Even after some constructive comments/advice, I haven't seen any difference and seems the User just ignores those and do not want to learn anything. I have off late downvoted any such posts and just moved on.

Comment: I move along, do not bother downvoting as it makes no difference. BTW, somebody downvoted THIS post.... huh?

Comment: Is there any way to add a "Shows no effort" flag and then expedite the closing of those posts?

Comment: My personal decision tree is (a) is the question, apropos of nothing, answerable? (b) if no, does the question, considering the user's history, appear to be fundamentally disrespectful of the community? I opt for downvote/close vote in the case of a false followed by true.

Comment: This is an interesting post. Playing devils advocate here...