# Let's Collaborate for canonical-qa's to help users

Tags: discussion

Based on comments from the [last Post](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/engaging-with-users-that-show-little-to-no-effort-in-learning) I opened, Wondering if we should start collaborating on creating those canonical posts.

I don't know if someone would like to propose a collaboration tool

(Trello for example) where we could dump TODO canonical posts on boards and assign ourselves to them, link a Github Repo to each and get stuff done?

I'm expecting 2 things from this post:

1. That we agree on some sort of collaboration tool for creating/tracking canonical TODOs
2. Determine what canonical posts are needed.

Comment: I definitely want to contribute, so definitely feel free to include me. I say we create a GitHub Team, and Trello or something. I think it would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: I'm also +1 for GitHub. Issues for task tracking, `.md` files with version control for collaborative drafting, wiki for everything else.

Comment: What's a canonical post?

Comment: @MartinLezer [canonical-qa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa)

Comment: Thanks @PranayJaiswal. I'd like to help if you agree.

Comment: Btw, we need a canonical answer to "why don't my unit tests pass, have enough coverage etc... I don't feel like doing it though - I've long since blocked those tags.

Comment: @CasparHarmer We have some now!

Comment: Haha... yes, there were 6! All hidden because of my ignored tags.